# Brew install fails on gpg-agent?

Tags: homebrew, gpg

Is there another way to get gpg-agent in? I need GPG2 signing for RVM in order to provision a server.

The message

```
bash-4.3$ brew install --vd gnupg2
==> Installing dependencies for gnupg2: gpg-agent, dirmngr, libusb, libusb-compat
==> Installing gnupg2 dependency: gpg-agent
==> Downloading ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/gnupg/gnupg-2.0.26.tar.bz2

curl: (28) Connection timed out after 5004 milliseconds
Trying a mirror...
==> Downloading ftp://ftp.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/gnupg/gnupg-2.0.26.tar.bz2

curl: (7) Failed to connect to ftp.mirrorservice.org port 21: Operation timed out
Error: Failed to download resource "gpg-agent"
Download failed: ftp://ftp.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/gnupg/gnupg-2.0.26.tar.bz2
```

Unfortunetly nothing too informative...

Answer (score 1):

Fixed with:

```
$ brew edit gpg-agent
    - mirror "ftp://ftp.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/gnupg/gnupg-2.0.26.tar.bz2"
    + mirror "http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/gcrypt/gnupg/gnupg-2.0.26.tar.bz2"

$ brew install gpg-agent
$ brew install gnupg2
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out! Please move this answer into the question you asked originally.